# Get databases directory for my app programmatically

Tags: android, database, sqlite, storage

I want to use a "pre loaded" database in my app. There are tons of questions about this and most point to this blog article [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) or similars.

So far so good. I just want to know if there is a better way to get the default databases directory so you don't have to use something like this:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";
```

I mean, maybe that is changed in the future or maybe a device or rom could place it elsewhere... so is there a way to get this path programatically?

In Context exists a method to getDatabasePath(name), but you need to give it an existing db name and well... it doesn't exist yet, I want to move it there :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Comment: See here:[programatically get the database path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55135337/8034839)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an empty DB, get the path with `getDatabasePath()`, then overwrite it with your own.

Comment: I was already doing this... but sounds like a hack :D But well... it sure works.

Comment: Well, since there is no official API to import a ready-made DB file, putting your own file there is a hack too. At least you are making sure you are putting it in the right place.

Comment: Do I need write permission for that?

Comment: @Simon, no special permission is needed for getDatabasePath()

Comment: See here:[programatically get the database path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55135337/8034839)

Answer (score 11):

I used...

```
String destPath = getFilesDir().getPath();
destPath = destPath.substring(0, destPath.lastIndexOf("/")) + "/databases";
```

Comment: What if the folder changes in a future release?

Answer (score 9):

Used by SQLiteAssetHelper:

```
 String path = mContext.getDatabasePath(mName).getPath();
```

At this time, the database doesn't exist. I think the String just takes the internal path and adds the appropriate modifiers. In fact, this seems to work just fine:

```
context.getDatabasePath("a").getParentFile()
```

Basically, you don't need to have a real database created, just ask it for one.

Comment: The database directory might not exist so before you write/copy any content to context.getDatabasePath("a") make sure to check that context.getDatabasePath("a").getParentFile() exists and if not create the directory.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Method `getFilesDir()` or `getDatabasePath` in an Activity-Class to get this Folder.
More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can use getDatabasePath method in your Helper class:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wl.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
    public String databasePath = "";    

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        // you can use an alternate constructor to specify a database location
        // (such as a folder on the sd card)
        // you must ensure that this folder is available and you have permission
        // to write to it
        // super(context, DATABASE_NAME, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        databasePath = context.getDatabasePath("wl.db").getPath();
    }
```