# Load database from downloaded file android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

```
    private void pullDatabase() {
    try {//standard filechannel download
        URL website = new URL(ip + "/questions.db");
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/questions.db"));
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code I use to pull the database from my server. How can I load the database afterwards?

Comment: Just download it into the proper `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/` folder.

Comment: move the database to the /data/data/youapplicationpackage/databases/

Comment: @kamran It's better to directly download it there. You avoid the move (copy + delete) step(s)

Comment: @DerGolem totally agree with you

Comment: @DerGolem Do i just type /data/data/package/databases/questions.db or something like getFilesDir() + "xxx" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12723245/2649012